# Cyclic events with RRULE from google-rfc-2445

Tags: icalendar, rfc2445

I wondering if it would be possible to represent cyclic events using RRULE from [google rfc 2445](http://google-rfc-2445.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rfc2445.html). An example would be birth control pills, which follow a cycle of X days of intake, then Y days of rest, and back to start.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

warning: I never used the google library.

From the [the newer standard RFC: RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), or also from [the old one RFC2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445), on which the Google library is built, the best way would be to have a recurence rule (`RRULE`) with a daily interval (`FREQ=DAILY`) and then set an interval of x+y days (say x+y=30 `INTERVAL=30`)and a duration of x days (`DTEND` x days later than `DTSTART`)

`DTSTART:20151101 DTEND:20151120 RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=30;`

Comment: Thanks, but `DTEND` doesn't work in that way. Your option will only repeat the first time, because you are creating an event wich repeats every 30 days (`FREQ=DAILY + INTERVAL=30`), but ends after `x` days (being `x < 30`).